# Can't understand validation logic: === vs ==

Tags: php, truthiness

I'm learning validation stuff, and I just can't understand this:

```
if (strpos($value, "@") === false) { echo "Validation failed." }
```

What's the difference between `===` and `==`? and why can't we use `==` instead and also why is it `=== false`? does false means that `@` is not in the `$value` or it means `0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Equality Operator `==`**
`A == B` checks whether A and B are equal to each other, but not whether they are the same data type.

A pertinent example: `0 == false` is true

**The Identity Operator `===`**
`A === B` checks whether A and B are equal to each other also the same data type.

A pertinent example: `0 === false` is false

**Application Here**

Applying this to your case, if the `@` was found as the first character of the string, `strpos($value,"@")` would return `0`. If it is not found at all, it would return `false`.

So to avoid confusing these two situations, the test must use `===` rather than `==`.

**Useful references:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

I've assumed this is php, but the equality and identity operators are common to many programming languages.

Comment: No worries. Please mark my answer as accepted by way of a thank you and to help other users find helpful information.

Comment: sorry didn't know , kinda new let me check